How to add sink connection to Postgresql in Debezium Kubernetes Operator manifest
I need to transfer data from postgresql (source) to another postgresql (destination) via debezium. I'm trying to run debezium in kubernetes via the kubernetes operator (installed from here https://github.com/debezium/debezium-operator). I'm using this manifest to deploy debezium instance:
apiVersion: debezium.io/v1alpha1
kind: DebeziumServer 
metadata:
  name: my-debezium 
spec:
  image: quay.io/debezium/server:3.0.0.Final 
  quarkus: 
    config:
      log.console.json: false
      kubernetes-config.enabled: true
  sink: 
    type: kafka
    config:
      producer.bootstrap.servers: <kafka_address>
      producer.key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      producer.value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
      tasks.max: 3
      topics: rkl.public.dm_rkl
      connection.url: jdbc:postgresql://<ip_destination_db>/<db_name>
      connection.username: <user>
      connection.password: <password>
      transforms.unwrap.type: io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
      auto.create: true                                                   
      insert.mode: upsert
      delete.enabled: true                                             
      primary.key.mode: record_key
      heartbeat.interval.ms: 5000   
      table.name.format: dm_rkl.dm_rkl
      schema.evolution: basic
      pk.mode: kafka
  source: 
    class: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
    config:
      offset.storage.file.filename: /debezium/data/offsets.dat
      plugin.name: pgoutput
      heartbeat.interval.ms: 5000
      slot.name: rkl_debezium
      publication.name: rkl_publication
      database.history: io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory
      database.hostname: <ip_source_db>
      database.port: 5432
      database.user: <user>
      database.password: <password>
      database.dbname: <db_name>
      topic.prefix: <prefix_for_topic>
      table.include.list: <table_name_for_source_db>

But for some reason insertion into the destination postgresql database does not work via a sink connection, using the io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector class. New records arrive from the source database to kafka, but the destination database does not respond to messages in kafka topic and does nothing.

Is there misconfiguration in my manifesе, that sink connection can't connect to destinatinon postgresql?
Is it necessary for the path to the table in the source database to match in the destination database?


Firstly, check the operator or connector pod logs for errors
In any case, Debezium image shouldn't have JDBC Sink from Confluent installed; Debezium has its own class for the same.
Otherwise, use Strimzi to run Kafka Connect (where you can install Debezium plugins) , not use Debezium operator
